# Django: ValueError at /api/clients/shipping/ Cannot assign .. must be a "Purchaser" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to create new object using the class model **purchaserShippingDetail** using the instance of **Purchaser** class model but my way does not work.

I'm getting the error

> ValueError at /api/clients/shipping/
> Cannot assign "<CustomUser: Admin>": "purchaserShippingDetail.owner" must be a "Purchaser" instance.

**Purchaser model** file

```
class Purchaser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='customer_photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    data_added = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**purchaserShippingDetail** model

```
class purchaserShippingDetail(models.Model):

    frequent_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = models.OneToOneField(Purchaser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="purchaser_shipping")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner.name
```

**views.py** file

```
class purchaserShippingDetailsListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = purchaserShippingDetailSerializer
    queryset = purchaserShippingDetail.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = self.request.user
        serializer.save(owner=user)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class purchaserShippingDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = purchaserShippingDetail
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add user as owner yet they are not related

user = self.request.user // this gets logged in user

serializer.save(owner=user) in this case owner and user are different things

Comment: How do i a get an instance of  ``Purchaser model``? i have tried updating the views by adding ``def perform_create(self, serializer): serializer.instance.owner = self.kwargs.get('pk') serializer.save()`` but it's not working.